# i tried disabling my remote session with this command

Tags: sudo, remote, xrdp, session, samba4

sudo systemctl disable xrdp $ sudo systemctl stop xrdp sudo apt purge xrdp sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-core sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-all sudo apt purge xorgxrdp

then i had to enter my password, i received Invalid unit name "$" escaped as "\x24" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
Unit /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service is masked, ignoring. from the terminal i tried unmasking sudo.service with systemctl unmask sudo.service  but it still didn't work cause the terminal still said Unit /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service is masked, ignoring. can anyone give me a solution to unmask  Unit /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service.

and how can i fix Invalid unit name "$" escaped as "\x24" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).

sorry for my english it's not my first language.

Comment: what i want to do is remove everything xrdp related.

Comment: Then add that important bit of info to the question jot as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The command you quote in the first line of your question does not make sense.
The error messages you are seeing are just helpless attempts to make sense of it anyway and are not to be taken seriously.
In particular, you *don't* want to unmask sudo.service.
You should rather be glad that the fact it is masked has prevented greater damage to your system.

It looks like you copied and pasted a block of commands you found somewhere on the 'net as a single line into your terminal window.
You need to enter each command on a line by its own, and not include the $ signs at the beginning of each line which are only there to show where a new command begins.

So the fix is to go back to the tutorial you copied that from, re-read it, understand what it is trying to do, and then enter the commands one by one.
The error messages will all disappear once you enter the commands correctly.

Comment: i fixed the commands by using sudo systemctl disable xrdp $ sudo systemctl stop xrdp sudo apt purge xrdp sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-core sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-all sudo apt purge xorgxrdp. but then it gave me this response from the terminal. Failed to disable unit: Unit file xrdp.service does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see in your comment what you did differently than in your question, it looks exactly the same.

Comment: well i fixed the commands and it gave me Failed to disable unit: Unit file xrdp.service does not exist.

Comment: That's what you wrote already. But your comment doesn't show the exact commands you ran so I cannot tell why it would emit that message. That said, it doesn't seem a problem to me. If you don't have a systemd unit for xrdp now then your goal of removing xrdp seems to have succeeded.